# Carbon parse Iso 8601 string to UTC date and record it to db

Tags: php, mysql, utc, php-carbon, iso8601

I have the following Iso8601 date-time string `2018-03-12T10:34:15-0200` and after I parse it

```
Carbon::parse("2018-03-21T10:34:15-0200", 'UTC')
```

and save it to mysql db `datetime` column I have `2018-03-21 10:34:15` so I've lost the `-0200` hours difference with UTC timezone.

Any ideas how to solve it the right way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need to pass time zone as a second parameter to parse function. Time zone is already part of date string. If you need to save date in UTC just convert it to UTC timezone after parsing like so:

```
Carbon::parse("2018-03-21T10:34:15-0200")->setTimezone('UTC')
```

Converted date will be: 2018-03-21 12:34:15.0 UTC (+00:00)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
Carbon::parse("2021-12-23T07:42:42.393Z")->setTimezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And the result will be like `2021-12-23 07:42:42`.