# How to convert ISO 8601 "20200823T203851.000Z" in readable date and time format using PHP in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, date, time, iso8601

I want to convert `"20200823T203851.000Z"` this date format into a readable format using PHP in a Laravel controller. I tried `date()` and it returns `"20200823UTC203851.0000"` as result, `strtotime()` does not seem to work.

```
 public function index() {

    $allCards = $this->getCardInfo();
    $clanInfo = $this->getClanInfo();
    $dateTime = $clanInfo->memberList[0]->lastSeen;

    //data stored on dateTime = '20200823T203851.000Z'
    //Required in readable format

    return view( 'claninfo', compact( ['allCards', 'clanInfo'] ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Carbon` to do so, please checkout it out from [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

now let's make the `$dateTime` readable:

```
 public function index() {

    $allCards = $this->getCardInfo();
    $clanInfo = $this->getClanInfo();
    $dateTime = $clanInfo->memberList[0]->lastSeen;

    //data stored on dateTime = '20200823T203851.000Z'
    //Required in readable format

    // here is the change:
    $dateTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateTime)->format('g:i a l jS F Y')
    // now $dateTime will be something like this: 7:30 pm Monday 24th August 2020

    return view( 'claninfo', compact( ['allCards', 'clanInfo'] ) );
}
```

Comment: Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
Could not parse '20200823T203851.000Z': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (20200823T203851.000Z) at position 16 (0): Unexpected character  , I am getting this error for digits after decimal  I guess that is millisecond or idk. How do I fix it ?

Comment: please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411340/php-datetimecreatefromformat-doesnt-parse-iso-8601-date-time and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505498/carbon-parse-iso-8601-string-to-utc-date-and-record-it-to-db and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525047/carbon-parse-to-iso8601 ... if you still have a problem please send again a comment to inform me